# WSO IS How to add a group to members of a group by SCIM API

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

We are working with WSO2 IS 5.1 with LDAP (embedded, in this time) as user store.

We would like to represent our organizational structure by group objects in LDAP (member attributes).

In SCIM API I add a user to group members properly, but when I try add group object to members of another group, IS interprets group id as user id and, of course, answers that there aren't any user with such id.
How could I add group to members of another group by SCIM API? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To creating a group with users, you need to have that user already existing in the user store and provide its unique id. For an example, to create a new group named: 'engineer' with user 'adam' as a member, you can invoke the following request

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"displayName": "engineer","members": [{"value":"6b14c23d-4811-4bbd-b653-04fcda2df266","display": "adam"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Groups
```

Comment: OK, but I would like to create a group with other groups as members. So I could represent a organization structure in LDAP. SCIM standart allows it. But it seems to me that in WSO2 IS SCIM I can't do it.

Comment: WSO2 Identity Server does not support nested groups yet.